# Source of Soul being a reflection of God or Bimba Prathibimba Vada in Vedas or Upanishads?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, upanishads

Praribimbavada is a vedantic argument which says God is the original image and all souls are the reflections of his image.

Where is it given anywhere in the Vedas or Upanishads that Soul is a reflection of God, or Atma is the reflection of Paramatma?

Comment: atma is satchidananda swarupa

Answer (score 2):

It is given in Brahma Sutra II.iii.50.

> And (**the individual soul) is only a reflection (of the supreme Self)**
> to be sure.

Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya II.iii.50 translated by Swami Gambhirananda

Comment: But is it not said anywhere in Upanishads or Puranas?

Comment: I am not sure if it is in Upanishads or Puranas..

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Soul is a reflection of Supereme God as written in Yajnavalkya Smriti 3:144.

> But just as the one ether becomes divided in the pots and the rest, so verily, **the one (Supereme) soul abides within many, like the sun within water-receptacles**

> Shwetashwara Upanishad II-16: This Divinity pervades all directions in their entirety. He is the first-born (Hiranyagarbha). He has entered into the womb. He alone is born, and is to be born in future. **He is inside all persons as the Indwelling Self**, facing all directions.

Comment: But where is bimba prathibimba here in Upanishads and Vedas. The verse quoted by you says God is inside all beings. But I'm asking for reflection of God in Soul.